# How to create .csv file from SQL with xp_cmdshell on linux shared folder with samba?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, samba, xp-cmdshell

So its kind of complicated I think, I've been searching all day for a solution.

I have a SQL Server 2008 R2 and with `xp_cmdshell` I currently generate some `.csv` files in `C:\`

What I want to do now is generate them directly into a linux server in the network.

I tried this :

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'NET USE T: \\192.168.0.25\PERSONS 123456 /user:linuxuser  /PERSISTENT:yes'
set @filepath = 'T:'

set @command ='echo '+@customerheader+' > '+@filepath+'\PERSONS\'+convert(varchar,123456)+'.csv'
set @command = replace(@command,'&','e')
exec master..xp_cmdshell @command

EXEC xp_cmdshell 'net use T: /delete'
```

And what I get is:  "The system cannot find the path specified." 
While the mapped drive is created succesfully: "The command completed successfully." and "T: was deleted successfully."

Thank you in advance

Comment: Outside of SQL Server/ when using SQLCMD or OSQL..  Can you simply use your `NET USE` commands and `Dir C:somefolder\*.* > T:\somefile.txt`

Comment: ye it works, it created the file

Comment: Can you show us your entire SQL Code?  I don't think you are showing us everything..  Understand NDA and such..  But, you need to show us how you are calling your SQL Query..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to get away from: xp_cmdshell

What about the following?

```
NET USE T: \\192.168.0.25\PERSONS 123456 /user:linuxuser  /PERSISTENT:yes

SET SQLSERVER=YOUR_sql_SERVER
SET SQLQUERY=C:\LOCALFOLDER\somequery.sql
SET OUTPUTFILE=T:\somefolder\someoutput.csv
sqlcmd -S %SQLSERVER% -d YOUR_DATABASE -U SQL_USER -P SQLPASSWORD -i"%SQLQUERY%" -o "%OUTPUTFILE%" -s"," -y30

net use T: /delete
```

I think the problem is that each time you invoke xp_cmdshell, you invoke a separate PID for CMD.exe and is a different session or instance and is causing you trouble.

Hope this helps!